# Maven, Tomcat and Java_Home / JRE_home variable

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

When I was trying to install Tomcat as a service, I kept getting the

> "JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined"

error even though my Java_Home was set to my jre. I tried putting my JDK, then updated my Java and put my new JRE, then what solved the problem was erasing the Java_Home variable, setting the JRE_HOME variable to the JRE (C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1) and then restarting. And the error finally went away and I could install/run Tomcat as a service.

But now I'm trying to use Maven, and before, it used to allow me to make maven projects, but now, because I deleted my Java_Home variable, I'm getting this error:

> "JAVA_HOME not found in your environment. Please set the JAVA_HOME
>   variable in your environment to match the location of your Java
>   installation"

So I'm looking at the files in the maven directory, and the one called mvn.cmd has this:

```
@REM ==== START VALIDATION ====
if not "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto OkJHome
```

and also

```
:OkJHome
if exist "%JRE_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto chkMHome
```

So i'm really confused at how to fix this problem if my JRE_Home is set, and if my JAVA_HOME is not defined, it should be using my JRE_Home but maven isn't.

And if my JRE_Home is working for Tomcat, what do I need to do to get Maven to accept it?

Comment: Set a JAVA_HOME environment variable that points to where your JDK is installed and you're done.  Don't point JAVA_HOME at the JRE; prefer JDK directory that is the parent of /bin.

Comment: Will this mess up with Tomcat? Because Tomcat would only run as a service after I REMOVED the Java_Home variable completely and only used JRE_home

Comment: You messed up Tomcat by touching the scripts.  Leave those alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to `(DRIVE):\Program Files\Java\jdk` & set the JRE_HOME variable to `(DRIVE):\Program Files\Java\jre\bin`

You're all set.